# php time difference script problem

Tags: php

here is my php code.....

```
<?php
function nicetime($date)
{
    if(empty($date)) {
        return "No date provided";
    }

    $periods         = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
    $lengths         = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

    $now             = time();
    $unix_date  = strtotime($date);

       // check validity of date
    if(empty($unix_date)) {    
        return "Incorrect Date";
    }

    // is it future date or past date
    if($now > $unix_date) {    
        $difference     = $now - $unix_date;
        $tense         = "ago";

    } else {
        $difference     = $unix_date - $now;
        $tense         = "ago";
    }

    for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    }

    $difference = round($difference);

    if($difference != 1) {
        $periods[$j].= "s";
    }

    return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
}
?>
```

but it is not showing the time correctly....and if any current time is given to it is showing 25-35 seconds ago and so on....but i want to make a time difference funtion like digg.com in a format like 2 Mints AND 3 Sec ago... how can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it to do with the other way - at the beginning multiply all `$lengths` values (i.e. `$multiplied`).
1. Divide `$difference` with that value.
2. If >= 1 then you have a solution.
   Else divide `$multiplied` with the `array_pop($lengths)` value. Go to 2.
3. You have the solution.

I think it would be it.

BTW - `$tense` is always `"ago"`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at and learn from the `Date::span` and `Date::fuzzy_span` methods of the [Kohana Date class](http://github.com/kohana/core/blob/master/classes/kohana/date.php).